# Django model method: how to refer to itself?

Tags: django, django-models

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def gen(self):
        return AnotherClass(self)  # Here I want to pass the class A instance
```

Is this the write way to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first named argument in a normal method is passed the instance the method was called on. So, yes.